# Apache Reverse Proxy setup with some exemptions

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, mattermost

I would like to install Mattermost on my server also running ISPConfig hosting software.
ISPConfig has a mechanism to automatically obtain and install Letsencrypt certificates based on the hostname. For this, Letsencrypt needs access to the `/.well-known` directory *(I guess)* to check for some verification string.

My Mattermost system is running on port 8065 and uses my ISPConfig hosting environment running on the same server as Reverse Proxy for SSL offloading.

I was following the instructions on https://docs.mattermost.com/configure/config-proxy-apache2.html which is working fine for unencrypted connections.

But as soon as I try to obtain a SSL certificate, this does not work anymore. I am not fully sure what's going on, but I guess that above mentioned code is proxying ALL the traffic to my mattermost system, while it should NOT proxy requests to the directory ./well-known which is needed for the letsencrypt stuff.

Does that sound reasonable?
If so, how can I exempt the `./well-known` directory from the proxying function?

(Maybe this is fairly easy for an expert, but I do not really know where to start - maybe because I do not fully understand how this reverse proxying works and what all the apache directives mean exactly...)

Here's a snippet of my current modifications to the standard apache vhost configuration:

```
ServerAdmin my.address@mydomain.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8065%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

ProxyPass /.well-known/ !  # <-- I inserted this line, but this does not seem to work...

<Location />
      Require all granted
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8065/
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8065/
      ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 mattermost.mydomain.com
</Location>
```

(I've stolen the above modification from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651809/no-lets-encrypt-renewal-with-reverse-proxy-in-ispconfig3, but that does not seem to work. Maybe because of the `<Location />` statement? But how to specify the whole directory `/` without `/well-known` in my `<Location>` statement?)

Any ideas on how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I was giving up too early.
I think I found out how to solve the problem.
In addition to `<Location>`, there's also a `<LocationMatch>` which works with regular expressions.
I am not an expert with regular expressions, but after some fiddling around, I found that the following directive did the trick:

```
<LocationMatch "^(?:(?!\/\.well-known).)*$">
```

If my understanding is correct, this matches all directories not beginning with `/.well-known`.